# Add a row to all tables inside a cell (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I want to add the first row of A above all tables inside a cell (namely CELL). the second column of a is a date. 
I tried using this code but it is unsuccessful.

```
NewCELL = cellfun(@(x) addvars(x,A) ,CELL,'uni',false);
```

Here is error message:

> Error using tabular/subsasgnDot (line 201) To assign to or create a
>   variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the
>   table.
>
> Error in tabular/addvars (line 165)
>       b = b.subsasgnDot(newvarnames{ii}, varargin{ii});
>
> Error in @(x)addvars(x,A)

I'm new to Matlab I wish someone help me to add the first row of A, Above all existing rows of tables that stored in a CELL.
[Here is my data.](http://8upload.ir/uploads/f443955780.zip)

Thank you

Comment: add a row `A` as the first to all tables?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding
Yes, A is a (1x3) table I want to add it above all rows of tables of CELL. the tables that stored in a CELL are 1x3 too. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need might be `vertcat`, which is vertical concatenation, i.e.,

```
NewCELL = cellfun(@(x) vertcat(A,x) ,CELL,'uni',false);
```